# Use jquery to find the input inside a div not working as expected

Tags: jquery

I have a table with inputs and I would like to click on a button and then get the values of some inputs. I just don 't understand how to get there in an easy way as my code is returning undefined all the time.

Code for the table:

```
<table align="center" class='hovertable' width="90%">
    <tr>
        <div class='line' name='div1'>
            <input id='' class='rpiid' type='hidden' name='rpiid[0]' value='00000000c83de86' />
            <input id='' class='sensor_id' type='hidden' name='sensor_id[0]' value='1' />
            <input id='' class='when' type='hidden' name='when[0]' value='2014-02-24 05:00:03' />
            <td align='center'>2014-02-24</td>
            <td>
                <input id='' class='val_displayed' type='text' name='val[0]' value='0366167' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id='' class='train' type='checkbox' name='train[0]' value='True' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id='' class='valid' type='checkbox' name='valid[0]' value='True' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <button id='0' class='submit_button' type='submit' name='button' value='update'>update</button>
            </td>
        </div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <div class='line' name='div2'>
            <input id='' class='rpiid' type='hidden' name='rpiid[1]' value='00000000c83de86' />
            <input id='' class='sensor_id' type='hidden' name='sensor_id[1]' value='1' />
            <input id='' class='when' type='hidden' name='when[1]' value='2014-02-25 05:00:03' />
            <td align='center'>2014-02-25</td>
            <td>
                <input id='' class='val_displayed' type='text' name='val[1]' value='0366132' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id='' class='train' type='hidden' name='train[1]' value='False' />
                <input id='' class='train' type='checkbox' name='train[1]' value='True' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id='' class='valid' type='hidden' name='valid[1]' value='False' />
                <input id='' class='valid' type='checkbox' name='valid[1]' value='True' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <button id='1' class='submit_button' type='submit' name='button' value='update'>update</button>
            </td>
        </div>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Code for jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.submit_button').click(function () {
        var val = $(this).closest('.when').attr('value');
        alert('the value is ' + val);
        return false;
    });
});
```

The jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/starcraft04/BLCJ5/10/

Thanks if you can help,

John.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML not valid,So that you don't get the expected result.If you want to get the result,You need to put the elements in a **td**

```
    <table align="center" class='hovertable' width="90%">
<tr>
    <td>
    <div class='line' name='div1'>
        <input id='' class='rpiid' type='hidden' name='rpiid[0]' value='00000000c83de86' />
        <input id='' class='sensor_id' type='hidden' name='sensor_id[0]' value='1' />
        <input id='' class='when' type='hidden' name='when[0]' value='2014-02-24 05:00:03' />
        </div>
</td>
        <td align='center'>2014-02-24</td>
        <td>
            <input id='' class='val_displayed' type='text' name='val[0]' value='0366167' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id='' class='train' type='checkbox' name='train[0]' value='True' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id='' class='valid' type='checkbox' name='valid[0]' value='True' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id='0' class='submit_button' type='submit' name='button' value='update'>update</button>
        </td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <div class='line' name='div2'>
        <input id='' class='rpiid' type='hidden' name='rpiid[1]' value='00000000c83de86' />
        <input id='' class='sensor_id' type='hidden' name='sensor_id[1]' value='1' />
        <input id='' class='when' type='hidden' name='when[1]' value='2014-02-25 05:00:03' />
         </div>
</td>
        <td align='center'>2014-02-25</td>
        <td>
            <input id='' class='val_displayed' type='text' name='val[1]' value='0366132' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id='' class='train' type='hidden' name='train[1]' value='False' />
            <input id='' class='train' type='checkbox' name='train[1]' value='True' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id='' class='valid' type='hidden' name='valid[1]' value='False' />
            <input id='' class='valid' type='checkbox' name='valid[1]' value='True' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id='1' class='submit_button' type='submit' name='button' value='update'>update</button>
        </td>

    </tr>
   </table>
```

**Javascript**

```
  $('.submit_button').click(function () {
       var val = $(this).closest('tr').find('.when').val();
       alert('the value is ' + val);
       return false;
   });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shijin/BLCJ5/16/)

Answer (score 1):

That's because when you write:

```
$('.submit_button').click(function () {
    var val = $(this).closest('.when').attr('value');
```

the element with class `when` must be a parent (or grand parent or grand grand parent etc.) of the submit button.

Try this: (Find closest `.line` from `.submit_button`, and then find a `.when` there)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.submit_button').click(function () {
        var val = $(this).closest('.line').find('.when').attr('value');
        alert('the value is ' + val);
        return false;
    });
});
```

I also edited your HTML, see it in the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BLCJ5/15/

The problem was that you cannot place `div`s as direct children of `<tr>` element.

Comment: I just tried your code in http://jsfiddle.net/starcraft04/BLCJ5/14/ but it is not working in fiddler :(

Comment: I have tested your edit too but still undefined in fiddler. See my comment before with the fiddler number 14.

Comment: Wow finally it works. It is strange that it is not working with div but it is working with tr. I don't understand why though. But really thanks for your help.